# node-gcm: send PushNotification for all device

Tags: node.js, push-notification, ionic2

I am trying  to build PushNotification sever using node.js,
I used "node-fcm" but it is not work with me, soIi tryed to use "node-gcm", but I faced same problem, I don't know how to send notifcation for all users? what I need to write in field (to:)??

this is my code:

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');
var Sender_ID = '55*****';
var API_KEY = 'my server key';
var sender = new gcm.Sender(API_KEY,{'proxy':'http://username:password@my_proxyinternet.com:8080' , timeout: 5000});
var message = new gcm.Message({
    notification: {
        title: "Hello, World",
        icon: "ic_launcher",
        body: "This is a notification that will be displayed."
    }
});

var registrationTokens = [];
registrationTokens.push(['All']); 
sender.send(message, { registrationTokens: 'All' }, function (err, response) {
    if (err) console.error(err + '  ERROR');
    else console.log(response + '  ELSE');
});
```

the result is:

> { multicast_id: -1,   success: 0,   failure: 1,   canonical_ids: 0,  results: [ { error: 'InvalidRegistration' } ] } Error: Recipient key 'registrationTokens' was provided as an incorrect type.  ERROR Process finished with exit code 0

Note: I use Ionic 2 and I can receive notifcation from https://console.firebase.google.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem resolved, in fact I didn't find solution to send notification to all user, so I used Topics in android app like this:
 in my ionic app I add topics option to android options like:

```
const options: PushOptions = {
  android: {
    topics:['A123'],
    senderID: "55*********5"
  }
```

and for server I used this [repositery](https://github.com/ToothlessGear/node-gcm)

at the End  I write this code to index.js file:

```js
var gcm = require('./lib/node-gcm');

var message = new gcm.Message();
message.addNotification({
    title: 'Alert!!!',
    body: 'Abnormal data access',
    icon: 'drawable-hdpi-icon',
    image: 'drawable-hdpi-icon',
    alert: 'true',
    sound: 'true'
});
//Add your mobile device registration tokens here
RETRY_COUNT = 4;
var regTokens = 'AAAAgXm-v**:***************************************************EaH';

var sender = new gcm.Sender(regTokens,{'proxy':'http://Username:Password@my_proxy.com:8080' , timeout: 5000});

sender.send(message, { topic: "/topics/A123" }, RETRY_COUNT, function (err, response) {    
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
    } else {
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

this is all steps, I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

and if you want to use FCM-PUSH; this is true Example:

```js
var FCM = require('fcm-push')

var SERVER_API='AAA*****************************jEaH';//put your api key here
var fcm = new FCM(SERVER_API)
var message = { 
    to: "/topics/A123",
    //collapse_key: '55',
    priority: 'high',
    content_available: true,
    notification: {
        title: 'Title of your push notification',
        body: 'Body of your push notification'
    },
    data: {  //you can send only notification or only data(or include both)
        my_key: 'my value',
        my_another_key: 'my another value'
    }
}

fcm.send(message, function(err, response){
    if (err) {
        console.log("Something has gone wrong!")
    } else {
        console.log("Successfully sent with response: ", response)
    }
})
```